# AWS RDS - How to make private a Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to make private a public snapshot.

[image]

[image]

I performing the next AWS CLI command to do that:

```
PS C:\Users\amrs> aws rds modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier snapshot-name-01 --attribute-name restore --values-to-remove all

An error occurred (InvalidDBClusterSnapshotStateFault) when calling the ModifyDBClusterSnapshotAttribute operation: automated snapshots cannot be modified.
```

Comment: How did you take the snapshots? Only manual snapshots can be modified using `modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute`

Comment: Those are System Snapshots, is there a way to modify them?

Comment: Unfortunately no. https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster-snapshot-attribute.html clearly says Adds an attribute and values to, or removes an attribute and values from, a **manual** DB cluster snapshot.

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem of concept and  understanding.